# FirstOrDefault, Nullable-поле и прозводительность

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Используется EF6 (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework). Режим database-first.
Есть модель

```
public partial class Bar
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public System.Guid Field_1 { get; set; }
    public string Field_2 { get; set; }
    public string Nullable_Field { get; set; }
}
```

Nullable_Field может принимать значения NULL.

Есть LINQ-запрос

```
string argument = GetStringArgument();
var bar = await myDbContext.Bars.FirstOrDefaultAsync(b=>b.Nullable_Field == argument);
```

Который генерит следующий SQL

```
SELECT "Extent1"."FIELD_1"     AS "FIELD_1",
        "Extent1"."FIELD_2"     AS "FIELD_2",
        "Extent1"."NULLABLE_FIELD"     AS "NULLABLE_FIELD"
FROM "FOO"."BAR" "Extent1"
WHERE
        (
                (
                        "Extent1"."NULLABLE_FIELD" = :p__linq__0
                )
                OR
                (
                        (
                                "Extent1"."NULLABLE_FIELD" IS NULL
                        )
                        AND
                        (
                                :p__linq__0 IS NULL
                        )
                )
        )
        AND
        (
                ROWNUM <= (1)
        )
```

Это проблема. Я понимаю, что запрос учитывает, что я могу передать аргумент со значением null(c#) и он мне вернёт записи с значением NULL(database). Но мне такой сценарий не интересен, аргумент у меня всегда не null. А блок условия с проверкой на NULL убивает производительность запроса, и имеющийся в базе данных индекс по Nullable_Field не спасает. Как объяснить EF, что меня не интересуют значения NULL, что я обязуюсь передавать не null-аргумент, что блок с NULL не нужен в sql-запросе.

Comment: А что будет с запросом, если подкинуть Where - `myDbContext.Bars.Where(_ => _.Nullable_Field != null).FirstOrDefaultAsync(b=>b.Nullable_Field == argument)`?

Comment: Посмотрите на ответы здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433594/why-is-ef-generating-sql-queries-with-unnecessary-null-checks

Comment: А причём здесь метка Oracle? В базе же вы ничего менять не собираетесь.

Comment: @0xdb, это база данных с которой я работаю. Это может быть важно, например потому что данная проблема, теоретически, может не воспроизвестись на других БД.

Comment: @0xdb перепроверил https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info --- я не нарушил ничего ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @4per Я не говорил, что вы что-то нарушаете ))

Comment: @4per ну в худшем случае всегда можно использовать `Database.SqlQuery()`

Comment: @yolosora Если даже в таких случаях использовать запрос через строковые литералы, то лучше уж сразу Dapper или\и хранимки.

Comment: Возникла подобная проблема. Удалось решить? Не могли бы вы поделиться решением.

Comment: Я аналогично пытался оптимизировать запросы с Nullable-полями, только БД была Sql Server. В итоге меняли схемы таблиц: везде где можно, отказались от null. Ввели дефолтные значения наподобие `-1`, `00/00/00` для даты и т. п. Семантически криво, зато эффективно.

Comment: @user393721, к сожалению нет. По ряду других причин полностью переписали этот блок, и проблема отпала. Поэтому как её лучше решить мне до сих пор не ясно.

Comment: @user393721, попробуем объявить конкурс?